# How would you design this database using MongoDB? Or would you use a different kind of database?

Tags: sql, mongodb, database

I would like to use MongoDB for my next web project. Being only familiar with SQL databases so far, I'm wondering if this design makes sense for MongoDB and if it's scalable, or if there's a better way to do it:

Basically I will have a LOT of users who will all follow the same course to study vocabulary on my site. For each user, I need to keep track of the words he has studied (between 0 and 2000, probably 100 on average), how well he knows them and when he will have to review them again. I'd also like to keep track of the next few words coming up that he should learn for ease of reference, and some other details about the user. I thought of a design like this:

```
{
  "user" : "Judith",
  "country" : "Germany",
  "curr_unit" : 1,
  "curr_lesson" : 2,
  "words" : 
  {
     "我" : { "state" : 7, "next_review" : "2013-09-21 19:43:37 +0100" },
     "你" : { "state" : 7, "next_review" : "2013-09-21 19:43:37 +0100" },
     "是" : { "state" : 7, "next_review" : "2013-09-21 19:43:37 +0100" },
     "学生" : { "state" : 2, "next_review" : "2013-08-31 19:43:37 +0100" },
     "医生" : { "state" : 1, "next_review" : "now" },
     "吗" : { "state" : 1, "next_review" : "now" },
     ... (could be 0-2000 such items) ...
  },
  "next_words" : [ "他", "不", "她", "中国人", "美国人", "这", "老师", "好", "很", "谢谢" ],
}
```

Basically, I'm having doubts that this is how MongoDB is intended to be used because I can't seem to retrieve words by state, I can only retrieve all information about the user at once. Also, it's annoying having to treat timestamps as strings.

Should I be using an SQL database instead? I'm afraid that the vocabulary_users table would quickly get unmanageable with lots of users and on average 100 entries each.

As this is a spaced repetition system, most of the times I will access this document in order to figure out which words should be studied next (using a mix of "state" and "next_review"). The second most common type of access will be when either "state" or "next_review" have to be updated after a study session. The third most common type of access is updating "curr_lesson". Everything else occurs less than 10 times over the lifetime of the user.

Comment: It looks like you need to consider document designs that better fit your requirements. Mongodb has a date data type. There's no clear right answer.

Comment: That's exactly my question: how would you design a database to contain this information?

Comment: As written, I consider this too broad. To be effective, we'd need to know all the scenarios, developers, IT requirements, performance.... MongoDb isn't a good fit for everything.

Comment: To me, this quite seems to be a case when data _does_ have a schema, and thus would benefit from an ordinary RDBMS. But this is just an opinion.

Comment: WiredPrairie, as this is a spaced repetition system, most of the times I will access this document in order to figure out which words should be studied next (using a mix of "state" and "next_review"). The second most common type of access will be when either "state" or "next_review" have to be updated after a study session. The third most common type of access is updating "curr_lesson". Everything else occurs less than 10 times over the lifetime of the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't seem like making a lot of sense. First, why have you decided to make "words" an object? If anything, it should be an array. It seems like you are building some sort of spaced repetition system rather then a dictionary, so instead of answering queries like: what do we know about word "德国人", you rather want to answer question: which card has highest priority to be shown now. So, if you make "words" an array of objects in form of `{ "word" : "数据库", "state" : 7, "next_review" : "2013-09-21 19:43:37 +0100" }`, you can build an index on `{"user":1, "words.next_review:1}`.

Next, it seems like embedding "words", and maybe "next_words" as well, into the user document is not really good idea. Your "words" will constantly be updated, which will cause the whole user document to be rewritten. If the document doesn't fit into its old space, it will be reallocated, which in turn means that all indexes for this collection will have to be updated.

Last piece I want to add is that almost half of the space in your document is taken by keys. Keys are something that is repeated in each document and it's a good practice to make them very short.

Comment: Thanks! I'm indeed looking to make a spaced repetition system and yes, most accesses will be either figuring out which cards has the highest priority, or updating the next_review or state. How would you design that? 

I was under the impression that I need a key in order to access my array of words...

Answer (score 0):

You can almost certainly make this work in SQL, in MongoDB, or in some other kind of data store like Redis, or Lux.  If your interest is in learning MongoDB, then use MongoDB and figure out the solutions to your problems!  but if you just want to get the project working quickly and have easy access to a lot of tools, following a well-paved path, you should probably stick with Postgres or some other SQL database.  That's my advice.